# Using Django, should I implement two different url mapping logics in my REST API and web application, and how?

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, slug

I have a `Book` model an instance of which several instances of a `Chapter` model can be linked through Foreign Key:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    pass

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(to=Book, ...)
    
    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = "book"
```

I decided to use Django both for the RESTful API, using Django Rest Framework, and for the web application, using Django Template. I want them separate as the way should be open for another potential application to consume the API.

For several reasons including administration purposes, the API calls for a url mapping logic of this kind:

```
mylibrary.org/api/books/
mylibrary.org/api/books/<book_id>/
mylibrary.org/api/chapters/
mylibrary.org/api/chapters/<chapter_id>/
```

For my web application, however, I would like the user to access the books and their contents through this url mapping logic:

```
mylibrary.org/books/
mylibrary.org/books/<book_id>-esthetic-slug/
mylibrary.org/books/<book_id>-esthetic-slug/chapter_<chapter_order>/
```

The idea is the router to fetch the book from the <book_id>, whatever the slug might be, and the chapter according to its order and not its ID.

Now I need some advice if this is desirable at all or if I am bound to encounter obstacles.
For example, how and where should the web app's <book_id>/<chapter_order> be "translated" into the API's <chapter_id>? Or if I want the web app's list of books to offer automatically generated slugged links to the books, should it be done at the API or the web app level?

I'm pretty new to Django / DRF and web development in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double URLs are not a problem at all. It is used whenever the program renders views and has an API (perhaps for a mobile app) as well. What I usually do is have the `id` field be in the URL of the 'web' pages too, it is simpler for me to keep track of. However if you want to have a 'nice' slug in the URL, try this:

```py
"""
models.py
"""

import uuid

from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, null=False, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, null=False, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    book = models.ForeignKey(to=Book, ...)
    sort = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = "book"
        unique_together = [("book", "sort"), ]  # so that there is never two chapters with the same number
```

```
"""
urls.py
"""

from django.urls import path

from . import apiviews, views

urlpatterns = [
    # 'web' URLs
    path("books/", views.books, "book_list"),  # mylibrary.org/books/
    path("books/<str:book_slug>", views.book, "book"),  # mylibrary.org/books/harry-potter-and-the-prisoner-of-azkaban
    path("books/<str:book_slug>/chapter_<int:chapter>", views.chapter, "chapter"),  # mylibrary.org/books/harry-potter-and-the-prisoner-of-azkaban/chapter_2
    # API URLs
    path("api/books/", apiviews.books, "api_book_list"),  # mylibrary.org/api/books/
    path("api/books/<uuid:id>", apiviews.book, "api_book"),  # mylibrary.org/api/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459
    path("api/chapters/", apiviews.chapters, "api_chapters"),  # mylibrary.org/api/chapters/
    path("api/chapters/<uuid:id>", apiviews.chapter, "api_chapter"),  # mylibrary.org/api/chapters/c76a89ae-ad73-4752-991c-8a82e47d3307
]
```

```
"""
views.py
"""

from .models import Book, Chapter


def books(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.all()


def book(request, book_slug)
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(slug=book_slug)
    except Book.DoesNotExist:
        pass


def chapter(request, book_slug, chapter)
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(slug=book_slug)
        chapter = book.chapter_set.get(sort=chapter)
    except Book.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

```
"""
apiviews.py
"""

from .models import Book, Chapter


def books(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.all()


def book(request, id)
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    except Book.DoesNotExist:
        pass


def chapters(request):
    chapter_list = Chapter.objects.all()


def chapter(request, id)
    try:
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(id=id)
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

These files reflect how you suggested the URLs. I personally (and I don't say that is the correct way) would have the API views set up like this:

```
mylibrary.org/books/
mylibrary.org/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459
mylibrary.org/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459/chapters/
mylibrary.org/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459/chapters/3
# and then for example:
mylibrary.org/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459/comments/
mylibrary.org/books/b21a0af6-4e6c-4c67-b44d-50f8b52cd459/comments/295
```

I find this structure more comprehensive but I can't see any pros or cons against your version. Both work just as fine and there is a good reasoning behind both of them. One being *"API is just a way to access the database objects and so I should be able to pull an arbitrary chapter if I know the ID"*, the other *"I have books and books have chapters, so a chapter is a sub-thing of books"*.

Comment: Ok I'm glad to hear the mapping I'd come up with is valid. Your solution separates the REST API urls and web app urls in such a fashion that the latter seem to be totally independent of the former. So the web app doesn't actually "consume" the API, it just uses the same models with its own views. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @PierreMDL yes, that is correct. There is no need for the views to interact, each one does something very different.

Comment: @PierreMDL if you’re happy with my answer, please accept it! ☺️ have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on the same timezone. What if I wanted the web app to consume the API (and not rely on the server directly)? Would that be "bad"? How would `mylibrary.org/books/<str:book_slug>/` translate to `mylibrary.org/api/books/<uuid:id>` and `mylibrary.org/books/<str:book_slug>/chapter_<int:chapter>` translate to `mylibrary.org/api/chapters/<uuid:id>`?

Comment: The API does something different than the normal view. It returns a different type of response. There is no need to translate between them, each one does something different. That way you’d be taking the data out of the db, then converting it to JSON and then loading the JSON again and converting it to HTML. It is more efficient to render the HTML directly. What you could do and what people do is create a static UI in React and then access the API the same way as an app would do. That would save you the two views, but create the need for the separate UI project. I don’t usually do that.

Comment: OK! It took some time but now I really get your point. I think I was misunderstanding what an API is actually doing, and as long as I am the developper with the hand on the DB and stuff, I can write as many apps as I want without the intermediary of the API. That makes much more sense. The API must stay however (because there might be a desktop / mobile app in the future), but following (one of) your advices maybe I'll drop the django "frontend" and let my colleagues go React.

Comment: @PierreMDL sounds good. As long as you have someone to do the React frontend for you, that stuff is a mess! Was happy to help.